# How to show variable character codes in a button c#

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I've saved icon font character codes in database:

```
f130, f150, ...
```

How can I show this codes as Icon?

```
Button.Text = "\u" + IconEntity.Value; // Error: invalid escape character!
```

if i use string formating, the button's text did not show icon correctly!

```
    Button.Text = @"\u" + IconEntity.Value; //Button Text = \uf130
```

Comment: `f130` and `f150` are "PRIVATE USE AREA"s. Are you sure you want to use these?

Comment: What is the type of `IconEntity.Value`? `string` or `int`?

Comment: @Sweeper , that is an Icon font and we are using these characters in json and command line, so we should use character codes.

IconEntity.Value is string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write strings with an escape charecter, c# treats the following text as a single char. For example, writing the string `"\u0041"` Will result in the string printing as the single char `A`.

When you start writing `"\u"` and then break the string, it'll treat it as a sequence of charecters, rather than a single one.

What you can do, however is create a `char` variable from it's hex value. You can do it by simply casting an `int` variable or literal to `char`.

Try implementing something similar to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "41";
    var i = int.Parse(str, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    // Prints the char "A"
    Console.WriteLine((char) i);
}
```